# Send email once every 12 months to a particular user

Tags: email

I'd like to send an email (only one) to a specific user every 12 months after a given date. Would you please provide me with the PHP code that would allow me to specify the starting date and send the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`update_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) for a `WP_User` if [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) ends up empty.

Update a key with a future date for the next year:

```
$startDate=date('Y-m-d');
$futureDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($startDate)) );
```

Schedule an event in one year with [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) or use `'daily'` to check all users for a relative year date.

```
// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'future_email_date',
            'value'     => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare'   => '<=',
            'type'      => 'DATETIME',
        ),
    ),
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

When you find a match, use [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) to send your email.